# Executing Anti Join in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class Note(model):
    <attribs>

class Permalink(model):
    note = foreign key to Note
```

I want to execute a query: get all notes which don't have a permalink. 
In SQL, I would do it as something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Note WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT note FROM Permalink);
```

Wondering how to do this in ORM.

Edit: I don't want to get all the permalinks out into my application. Would instead prefer it to run as a query inside the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
 Note.objects.exclude(id__in=Permalink.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Comment: it is a weird slow approach

Comment: I just post another approach

Comment: and I've just commented it

Comment: Small correction, it should be .values_list('note', flat=True). Alternatively .values('note') also works.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use this query:

```
Note.objects.filter(permalink_set__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what permalink_set be ? I ran this in the shell and it doesn't work.

Comment: @AnilShanbhag: It's the related name of the Permalink foreign key. So, if you set a related name for the foreign key, use that.

Comment: @AnilShanbhag if `related_name` setted `note = models.ForeignKey('Note', related_name='permalinks')` so it should be `Note.objects.filter(permalinks__isnull=True)`