# Filter based on children_set count in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am filteren a children set as

```
ParentModel.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        lookup='childrenmodel_set',
        queryset=ChildrenModel.objects.exclude(is_active=False)
    )
)
```

Now each ParentModel object can have a `childrenmodel_set` but some of these querysets are empty.

How can I exclude those `ParentModel` objects which has no childrens?

I've thought of:

```
ParentModel.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        lookup='childrenmodel_set',
        queryset=ChildrenModel.objects.exclude(is_active=False)
    )
).exclude(childrenmodel_set=None)
```

or

```
ParentModel.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        lookup='childrenmodel_set',
        queryset=ChildrenModel.objects.exclude(is_active=False)
    ).aggregate(num_objects=Count(id))
).exclude(num_objects=0)
```

or

```
ParentModel.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        lookup='childrenmodel_set',
        queryset=ChildrenModel.objects.exclude(is_active=False)
    )
).annotate(childrenset_size=Count(childrenset)).exclude(childrenset_size=0)
```

I could of course check this in the template but I want to do it on database level.

## Edit:

Now my code is

```
self.model.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        lookup='periods',
        queryset=Period.objects.exclude(is_active=False)
    )
).exclude(periods__isnull=True)
```

It removes those objects which has no periods. But if an object has only non-active periods it is still represented in the queryset. How can I make the `exclude` take the prefetching into account?

## Edit 2

My models

```
class Article:
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

class Period:
    article = ForeignKey(Article)
    is_active = BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ParentModel.objects.exclude(childrenmodel_set__isnull=True)
```

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597837/executing-anti-join-in-django-orm/26597930#26597930

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's close to be working as I need. I've changed my question.

Comment: can you post your models?

Comment: `self.model.objects.exclude(periods__isnull=True, periods__is_active=False)` or `self.model.objects.exclude(periods__isnull=True).filter(periods__is_active=True)` and first use "Debug toolbar` and check number of queries and their content, then if you will have great bunch of them use `select_related` for FK, and `prefetch_related` if many_to_many

Comment: but don't use them, when you write code, it is only optimisation, second step

Comment: also use `python manage.py shell` and `print your_queryset.query` to see SQL